# Can Async function be used without await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, webrtc

I was going through the WebRTC documentation and I found the following piece of code.

```
 const openMediaDevices = async (constraints) => {
    return await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
}

try {
    const stream = openMediaDevices({'video':true,'audio':true});
    console.log('Got MediaStream:', stream);
} catch(error) {
    console.error('Error accessing media devices.', error);
}
```

Here, openMediaDevices() returns a promise while it have been used inside try{} block without any await. Will the program wait for openMediaDevices() to complete? If yes, how?

Comment: returning `Promise` and `async` are different. In fact, internally Javascript is probably using `Promise` to make things functional with `async` and `await` keywords

Comment: @canbax `async` and `await` are mostly syntactic sugar over promises to allow alternative syntax. They aren't different.

Comment: Duplicate Question, check the answer in the below link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77946819/2980414

Answer (score 2):

> Will the program wait for openMediaDevices() to complete?

No.

Comment: Then they have the wrong program? Please check https://webrtc.org/getting-started/media-devices#using-asyncawait.

Comment: In more detail the `webrtc.org` code is missing an `await` operatator between `const stream =` and the immediately following call to `openMediaDevices` (at least at October 2020).

Comment: Making the helper function to give `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` a shorter name `async` is also entirely pointless.

Comment: the tutorial on webrtc.org is wrong in this and other places...